# Starting Patrol tests brings "Serializer for class 'ConfigureRequest' is not found" error

Tags: flutter, flutter-integration-test, flutter-patrol

I've just switched from Patrol 2.2.5 to 2.3.0, and I'm getting this error when I try to run the test:

```
        Patrol (native): trying to configure() again in 1 second
        Patrol (native): configure() started
        Patrol (native): configure() failed
        Patrol (native): configure() failed: (NativeAutomatorClientException: configure() failed with Invalid response: 500 kotlinx.serialization.SerializationException: Serializer for class 'ConfigureRequest' is not found.
        Please ensure that class is marked as '@Serializable' and that the serialization compiler plugin is applied.

                at kotlinx.serialization.internal.Platform_commonKt.serializerNotRegistered(Platform.common.kt:91)
                at kotlinx.serialization.internal.PlatformKt.platformSpecificSerializerNotRegistered(Platform.kt:28)
                at kotlinx.serialization.SerializersKt__SerializersKt.serializer(Serializers.kt:134)
                at kotlinx.serialization.SerializersKt.serializer(Unknown Source:1)
                at pl.leancode.patrol.contracts.NativeAutomatorServer$router$2.invoke(NativeAutomatorServer.kt:211)
                at pl.leancode.patrol.contracts.NativeAutomatorServer$router$2.invoke(NativeAutomatorServer.kt:57)
                at pl.leancode.patrol.PatrolServerFiltersKt$catcher$1$1.invoke(PatrolServerFilters.kt:30)
                at pl.leancode.patrol.PatrolServerFiltersKt$cat
        Patrol (native): trying to configure() again in 1 second
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug in Patrol and was fixed in Patrol 2.3.1.

https://github.com/leancodepl/patrol/pull/1782